# Express morgan logging fails to skip logging keep-alive requests

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-elb, skip, morgan

I am running a node.js express app in AWS behind an Elastic Load Balancer.  I am using 'morgan' as my logging mechanism.

ELB sends a keep-alive request periodically, the target of which I have defined as a 1 char text file (keep-alive.txt).

Obviously, I don't want to see these requests in the log, so I have used the morgan skip function as follows:

```
// use morgan to log requests to the console
var morganOptions = {
    skip: function (req, res) {
        return req.get('/keep-alive.txt');  // don't log the load balancer keep alive pings
    }
};
app.use(logger('dev', morganOptions));
```

According to the [morgan doc](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#write-logs-to-a-file), returning TRUE to the skip function should cause the log skip.  However, morgan is logging every keep-alive fetch.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks a million!

Comment: Posted my comment as answer so you can pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `return req.url === '/keep-alive.txt'`